# Spyder IDE tells me my python version is incorrectly compiled (MAC)

Tags: spyder

I just downloaded Spyder IDE for my programming class. I had been using Replit for two months, so I figured this is high time I switched to Spyder.

The console shows this message:

"This version of python seems to be incorrectly compiled
(internal generated filenames are not absolute).
This may make the debugger miss breakpoints.
Related bug: [http://bugs.python.org/issue1666807"](http://bugs.python.org/issue1666807%22)

NOTE: I had installed Python a year ago using Atom, but then today, before installing Spyder, I deleted Python and all files related to it. Then, I downloaded latest version of Python from Python's website (3.10.1).

I tried to find a work around for this by going to preferences, Python interpreter, and selecting the interpreter I downloaded, which is named Python IDLE. But, every time I try selecting that, it says invalid file path (/Applications/Python 3.10/IDL

I tried looking this up, but I cannot find something that is beginner-friendly. Can someone help me understand what is causing this?

Comment: I had installed Python a year ago using Atom, but then today, before installing Spyder, I deleted Python and all files related to it. Then, I downloaded latest version of Python from Python's website (3.10.1).

Comment: Also, I tried to find a work around for this by going to preferences, Python interpreter, and selecting the interpreter I downloaded, which is named Python IDLE. But, every time I try selecting that, it says invalid file path (/Applications/Python 3.10/IDL)

Comment: Yes, I did that.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add conda-forge as prioritized channel, and I created new environment to install python and spyder-kernel again.

conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --set channel_priority strict
conda install

https://conda-forge.org/#about

I was thinking about clear my default 'base' environment, but that does not work well. Thus, I had to create new environment.
conda create --name myenv

https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands

After that I have to indicate new Python Interpreter on 'Preferences - Python Interpreter - Use the following Python Interpreter'.

Then, it works for now, but I have to install additional packages for my convenience later.
In conclusion, I can have Spyder application running through Rosetta 2 with Python Interpreter for Apple Silicon.

Python 3.10.2 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Jan 14 2022, 08:04:21) [Clang 11.1.0 ]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 8.0.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

My answer might be so rough, so please let me know how can I improve.